# Hierarchy of parser grammars vs Chomsky hierarchy of grammars and the comparsion of the language acceptance power of each parser grammar

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers, check-my-answer, chomsky-hierarchy

While reading the text *Modern Compiler Implementation in C* by *Andrew Appel* I came across the hierarchy of grammar given below.

[image]

The above diagram is very helpful in understanding the correlation among the various parser grammars. All the grammar above are context free grammars. From theory of computation texts, I have the following Chomsky hierarchy of grammars in my mind.

[image]

Now I wonder, how to correlate these two diagrams - a possible superposition, which shall show where exactly in the Chomsky hierarchy the parser grammars lie, and their extent with respect to the boundaries already defined by Chomsky hierarchy.

---

If possible, could you please as well suggest the resource from which I can develop more knowledge regarding this.

---

PS: After the comments and discussion in the answer by Yuval Filmus, I made an attempt to draw the situation:

---

[image]
*If we consider on the basis of the power of language corresponding to a grammar type*

---

[image]
*If we consider just on the basis of grammar type*

Reference : [Theory of Computation Lectures by Prof. Harry Porter](https://youtu.be/nDubPD0-7XY?t=770)

*Are the above diagrams which I have constructed as per my understanding correct?* If they are not then could anyone please rectify it...

Answer (score 3):

All of the grammars in your first figure are context-free grammars. That text seems to identify *grammar* with *context-free grammar*.

Comment: `All of the grammars in your first figure are context-free grammars`, yes (I figured it out while self studying, based on the fact that since we are considering parsing, only CFGs have parse trees) but what I was actually looking for is which of the grammars in the first diagram are a part of DCFG and which are not. Which of them are regular etc... I guess I was not above to express myself properly. Sorry.. :(

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: an ambiguous grammar cannot be deterministic because the ambiguity is a non-determinism, by definition. However, not all unambiguous grammars are deterministic. On the other hand, all LR(k) grammars are deterministic, again by definition: the LR parser is a deterministic parser.

Comment: @rici, as per your comments, I have made an edit to my question and have included my attempt of drawing the situation.

Comment: @yuvalfilmus could you please just check my diagram which I have added as a post script? The non deterministic context free grammar set - unambiguous grammar set, contains all the ambiguous grammars as per my understandings. And as you said the entire first picture is now inside the context free grammar set (or shell)